# Arranging 12 people in a circle-like table

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

[image: Problem]

Based on the picture, I want to solve Problem ⓐ.

Is the problem ⓐ same problem compared to problem ⓑ?

So we can suppose one of the people is a King, then the answer should be 11!

Am I right? :o

Comment: Please describe what problems ⓐ and ⓑ are. We can't tell from a picture of circles and rectangles what the problem is. It seems to be about people and maybe a King?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer depends on the problem you're trying to solve. Often such problems are about finding the number of *inequivalent* arrangements, where the notion of equivalence must be defined for the problem to be well-posed. In the present case, one might consider two arrangements around the tables to be equivalent if one is transformed into the other by a rotation. If so, the problems would be different, since the rectangular table has fewer rotations that leave its form invariant than the circular table.

Comment: So the answer should be 6 * 11! , is this right?

Comment: @Orange: The answer to what?

Comment: The problem A, in the picture above the question. Arranging 12 people in the ⓐ table.

Comment: @Orange: Please reread my answer. As I wrote, the result depends on the problem you're trying to solve. You haven't specified a notion of equivalence, so it's not a well-defined problem to ask how many arrangements there are. Without equivalence, there are simply $12!$ different arrangements, but I suspect that's not the problem you have in mind.